# Cannot add new events after calling close

Tags: flutter, class, dart, video, bloc

***Flutter***

i am using `video_trimmer: ^0.5.2` plugin , which allows cutting and editing the video before uploading ,on pressed so everything work fine from the first time but if i reopen the editor again by clicking the bottom, video will be shown without the TrimmerEditor widget with this error `Cannot add new events after calling close` but if left the page  and re-entered again, everything will work fine except if i click again and again with keeping in the same UI page !

**i already know that happen because of the widget which is close again from the stack IF (true or false ) but i need a solution with same my code cuse i have big complicated project in the same code**

```
    class VideoTrimmer extends StatefulWidget {
      const VideoTrimmer({Key key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _VideoTrimmerState createState() => _VideoTrimmerState();
    }
    
    
    class _VideoTrimmerState extends State<VideoTrimmer> {
    
      Trimmer _trimmer = Trimmer(); // this object from the package its self 
      double _startValue = 0.0;
      double _endValue = 0.0;
      bool _isPlaying = false;
      bool displayWidget = false;
    
    
      _loadVideo() {
        _trimmer.loadVideo(videoFile: file);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
       _trimmer.dispose(); // i tried to remove this too , but same issue
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false );
                    if (result == null) return;
                    final path = result.files.single.path;
                    setState(() => file = File(path));
                    _loadVideo();
                    setState(() => displayWidget = true);
                  },
                  child: Text("selectVideo")
              ),
              displayWidget ?
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: VideoViewer(trimmer: _trimmer),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: TrimEditor( // here is the issue happen 
                          trimmer: _trimmer,
                          viewerHeight: 50.0,
                          viewerWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          maxVideoLength: Duration(seconds: 60),
                          onChangeStart: (value) {
                            _startValue = value;
                          },
                          onChangeEnd: (value) {
                            _endValue = value;
                          },
                          onChangePlaybackState: (value) {
                            if(!mounted) {
                              setState(() =>
                              _isPlaying = value);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        child: _isPlaying
                            ? Icon(
                          Icons.pause,
                          size: 80.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                            : Icon(
                          Icons.play_arrow,
                          size: 80.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
          

              onPressed: () async {
                      bool playbackState = await _trimmer.videPlaybackControl(
                        startValue: _startValue,
                        endValue: _endValue,
                      );
                      if(!mounted) {
                        setState(() =>
                        _isPlaying = playbackState);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                     ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("SAVE"),
                    onPressed: ()  {
                      uploadVideo();
                      setState(() =>  displayWidget  = false);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
}
}
```